# kafka logs + how to limit the logs size

Tags: linux, hadoop, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, ambari

in my ambari cluster ( **version 2.6** )

we have master machines and workers machines
while kafka installed on the master machines

the partition /data is only **15G**
and kafka log folder is -  **/data/var/kafka/kafka-logs**

most of the folders under  /data/var/kafka/kafka-logs are with size 4K-40K

but two folders are very huge size - 5G-7G , and this cause **/data** to be 100%

example:

under **/data/var/kafka/kafka-logs/mmno.aso.prpl.proces-90**

```
12K     00000000000000000000.index
1.0G    00000000000000000000.log
16K     00000000000000000000.timeindex
12K     00000000000001419960.index
1.0G    00000000000001419960.log
16K     00000000000001419960.timeindex
12K     00000000000002840641.index
1.0G    00000000000002840641.log
16K     00000000000002840641.timeindex
12K     00000000000004260866.index
1.0G    00000000000004260866.log
16K     00000000000004260866.timeindex
12K     00000000000005681785.index
1.0G    00000000000005681785.log
```

is it possible to limit the size of the logs? or other solution ?
we have small **/data** and need logs should not be with 1G size , how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kafka has a number of broker/topic configurations for limiting the size of logs. In particular:

- `log.retention.bytes`: The maximum size of the log before deleting it
- `log.retention.hours`: The number of hours to keep a log file before deleting it

Note that these are not hard bounds as deletion happens per segment as described in: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#impl_deletes. Also these are per topic. But by setting these you should be able to control the size of your data directory.

See http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs for the full list of `log.retention.*`/`log.roll.*`/`log.segment.*` configs

Comment: I think log.retention.hours will not help because some topic folder under kafka-logs are 5-10G so in case we minimize it to 10 HOURS , then folder with huge size will already appears for MAX 10H

Comment: Then use `log.retention.bytes`. I mentioned all the possible configurations you can use to control the logs size, then it's up to you to find the combination that matches your cluster requirements.